# Google Maps Sharing - Can you set only creator of pin can delete/modify it?

Tags: google-maps

So i have a map that i am sharing with a wide range of people online through the link, anyone can edit it if they have the link.

What I noticed though is that anyone can  delete anyone else's pins, while i trust most of the people it is open and could be vandalized and have everything removed.

Is there a setting somewhere i can set so that only the person who created the pin/shape on the map can alter it?